# changing multiple dropdowns with ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a question regarding AJAX and PHP, I have a main drop down list and when the user changes it, other drop downs are supposed to be changed based on the main drop down value, to be more clear i have a quick finder part of the website i am working on, there is a pick up port(The main drop down), there is also 4 other drop downs that are supposed to be changed using AJAX and PHP when the user changes this pickup port one, does anyone have an idea how to create that, I have been working on it for like 3 days now, and not successful.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried this

```
function filter(id) {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('type_filter').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById('find-trip-dest-region').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'forms/type_filter.php?id=' + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'forms/activity_filter.php?id=' + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and also this

```
function filter(id) {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('type_filter').innerHTML = type_filter.responseText;
            document.getElementById('find-trip-dest-region').innerHTML = activity_filter.responseText;
        }
    }
    var type_filter = xmlhttp.open('GET', 'forms/type_filter.php?id=' + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    var activity_filter = xmlhttp.open('GET', 'forms/activity_filter.php?id=' + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and also tried this

```
function filter(id) {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('type_filter').innerHTML = type_filter.xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById('find-trip-dest-region').innerHTML = activit_filter.xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    var type_filter = xmlhttp.open('GET', 'forms/type_filter.php?id=' + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    var activit_filter = xmlhttp.open('GET', 'forms/activity_filter.php?id=' + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: What have you done/tried so far?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there

Comment: I also have tried alot of other stuff that i even don't remember right now but those are what i have tried just right now, sorry but i am really so very brand new in AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it using jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pickup_port').change(function() {
        var id = $('#pickup_port').val();
        if(id != "") {
            $.get('forms/type_filter.php?id='+ id, function(data) {
                $('#type_filter').html(data);
            });
            $.get('forms/activity_filter.php?id='+ id, function(data) {
                $('#activity_filter').html(data);
            });

        }
    });
});
```

But does anybody have a better solution or this is the only solution